# Mysql-Workbench 6.0 lost the ability to filter results by column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In Mysql-Workbench 5.x after running a query, I could right-click on a column in the results and select "filter column" or something like that.  I could then enter a value and only rows with that value in that column would be shown.

In 6.x, that capability seems to be gone.

Is it hidden somewhere or do I need to go back to 5.x?

Thanks.

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like something you'd write a query for. I don't see the option in 5.2.47, nor 6.3.3, so I'm unsure what you are referring to. Maybe instead use the "Filter Rows" filter there, or "Search Table Data".

Comment: Yes, In version 5.2.44 we can right click on column in Result Grid and apply filter over it. In newer version column wise filtering is removed ([check this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-develop-sql-editor-results.html)) and a textBox is provided where we can enter any text and a case-insensitive search is performed on all the cell. BUT I LIKED THE FUNCTIONALITY GIVEN IN PREVIOUS VERSION (5.2.44), BECAUSE WE CAN PERFORM COLUMN WISE FILTRATION THEIR.

Comment: Amogh - thanks for adding the picture.  Yes, that is the capability that is lost in the 6.x versions.  I see this as a major fault in the 6.x versions as it is something I used all the time.

Comment: @emann, I have opened an discussion on Mysql forum also (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,631692,631692#msg-631692), lets hope that we will get some proper reply.